# How do I set/change the alphaInfo on a CGImage?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-image

I am using this extension to get the pixel color:

```swift
extension UIImage {
    subscript (x: Int, y: Int) -> UIColor? {
        guard x >= 0 && x < Int(size.width) && y >= 0 && y < Int(size.height),
            let cgImage = cgImage,
            let provider = cgImage.dataProvider,
            let providerData = provider.data,
            let data = CFDataGetBytePtr(providerData) else {
            return nil
        }

        let numberOfComponents = 4
        let pixelData = ((Int(size.width) * y) + x) * numberOfComponents

        let r = CGFloat(data[pixelData]) / 255.0
        let g = CGFloat(data[pixelData + 1]) / 255.0
        let b = CGFloat(data[pixelData + 2]) / 255.0
        let a = CGFloat(data[pixelData + 3]) / 255.0

        return UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when I run using a playground or a simulator, but when I run it on my device (iPhone XR) I got different values.

After some time debugging I found when I use a simulator the cgimage have the alphaInfo **kCGImageAlphaLast** and when I use the device the alphaInfo is **kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast**

Debug:

```
// Simulator
<CGImage 0x7f9f674150f0> (IP)
    <<CGColorSpace 0x600002893120> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)>
        width = 1000, height = 500, bpc = 8, bpp = 32, row bytes = 4000 
        kCGImageAlphaLast | 0 (default byte order)  | kCGImagePixelFormatPacked 
        is mask? No, has masking color? No, has soft mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? Yes
// -------------------------------------------- //

// Device
<CGImage 0x7f88df70d980> (DP)
    <<CGColorSpace 0x6000003dc540> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)>
        width = 1000, height = 500, bpc = 8, bpp = 32, row bytes = 4000 
        kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | 0 (default byte order)  | kCGImagePixelFormatPacked 
        is mask? No, has masking color? No, has soft mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? Yes
```

Since alphaInfo is a read only property, is there any way to set that or recreate setting the alphaValue to `kCGImageAlphaLast`.

I found that multiplies the colors value by alpha value, but I am I little confusing how to "recover" the "correct" value.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgimagealphainfo/kcgimagealphapremultipliedlast

Comment: Solved: See the answer bellow.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Since Apple Said:

**kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast**

`The alpha component is stored in the least significant bits of each pixel and the color components have already been multiplied by this alpha value. For example, premultiplied RGBA.`

It's surpresilly easy to fix, yours RGB values are multiplied by the alpha value, so, you just need to revert this.

```
premultiplied.R = (straight.R * straight.A / 255);
premultiplied.G = (straight.G * straight.A / 255);
premultiplied.B = (straight.B * straight.A / 255);
premultiplied.A = straight.A;
```

So, we just need to do the opposite:

```
straight.R = (premultiplied.R / straight.A) * 255;
straight.G = (premultiplied.G / straight.A) * 255;
straight.B = (premultiplied.B / straight.A) * 255;
straight.A = premultiplied.A;
```

I create this extension to get the **correct** color of a pixel:

```swift
extension UIColor {

    func rgb(alphaInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo) -> (red: UInt8, green: UInt8, blue: UInt8, alpha: UInt8) {

        var fRed : CGFloat = 0
        var fGreen : CGFloat = 0
        var fBlue : CGFloat = 0
        var fAlpha: CGFloat = 0

        if self.getRed(&fRed, green: &fGreen, blue: &fBlue, alpha: &fAlpha) {

            var iRed = fRed * 255.0
            var iGreen = fGreen * 255.0
            var iBlue = fBlue * 255.0
            let iAlpha = fAlpha * 255.0

            switch alphaInfo {
            case .premultipliedLast, .premultipliedFirst:
                iRed = (iRed / iAlpha) * 255
                iGreen = (iGreen / iAlpha) * 255
                iBlue = (iBlue / iAlpha) * 255
            default:
                break
            }

             return (red:UInt8(iRed.rounded()),
green:UInt8(iBlue.rounded()), 
blue:UInt8(iGreen.rounded()), 
alpha:UInt8(iAlpha.rounded()))
        } else {
            // Could not extract RGBA components:
            return (0, 0, 0 , 0)
        }
    }
}
```